# How do I implement something like cron job on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron

I know about Heroku Scheduler addon but is it very flexible like I want to be able run a task on the 1st and 15th of every month as well as at daily intervals.

What else can I use or is Scheduler the best option for Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

According to my knowledge Scheduler is the best option. It is good and reliable go for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you lowest frequency of running a task is it daily then config scheduler to run daily and then in the code that it runs check the day of the month and perform your desired tasks whether it be day 1, day 15 or day x.

If that doesn't suit then you'd need to look at one of the background processors like Sidekiq, DelayedJob etc that allowed scheduled jobs and then have your jobs requeue themselves at whatever frequency you want but you'll need to be running a worker for this to work in a similar fashion to scheduler.